# Sporadic unusually slow performance for inserting a single row into PostgreSQL database table

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, amazon-aurora

I am using a combination of Amazon Aurora (Aurora PostgreSQL    11.6) and Entity Framework Core to perform (among other Db operations) a very simple 1 row insert into a relatively small (33k) record table.

A majority of the time the insert takes in the single digit ms, but occasionally I notice the insert takes around 950ms. I don't really understand what is causing this? Whenever I try reviewing an EXPLAIN/ANALYZE it shows me nothing much, as its just an insert with a returning id. I can't see any obvious issues here. It's also strange that no other inserts seem affected by this sporadic 'slowness'. Can anyone assist?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE request_to_print (
    request_internal_id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    card_number VARCHAR(100),
    customer_internal_id UUID NOT NULL,
    requested_date TIMESTAMP,
    requesting_store VARCHAR(10),
    request_sent_date TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY ("request_internal_id")
);
```

Sample statement:

```
INSERT INTO request_to_print (card_number, customer_internal_id, request_sent_date, request_type, requested_date, requesting_store)
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5)
RETURNING request_internal_id;
```

Output from an explain/analyze

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "ModifyTable",
      "Operation": "Insert",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Relation Name": "request_to_print",
      "Schema": "public",
      "Alias": "request_to_print",
      "Startup Cost": 0,
      "Total Cost": 0.01,
      "Plan Rows": 1,
      "Plan Width": 422,
      "Actual Startup Time": 0.072,
      "Actual Total Time": 0.073,
      "Actual Rows": 1,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Output": [
        "request_internal_id"
      ],
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 3,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
      "I/O Read Time": 0,
      "I/O Write Time": 0,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Result",
          "Parent Relationship": "Member",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Startup Cost": 0,
          "Total Cost": 0.01,
          "Plan Rows": 1,
          "Plan Width": 422,
          "Actual Startup Time": 0.02,
          "Actual Total Time": 0.02,
          "Actual Rows": 1,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Output": [
            "uuid_generate_v4()",
            "''::character varying(100)",
            "'5687afea-52cd-4e11-8278-9a71fb9f5982'::uuid",
            "'2021-05-14 06:24:17.424055'::timestamp without time zone",
            "''::character varying(10)",
            "'2021-05-14 06:24:17.424055'::timestamp without time zone",
            "''::character varying(50)"
          ],
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
          "I/O Read Time": 0,
          "I/O Write Time": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "Planning Time": 0.02,
    "Triggers": [],
    "Execution Time": 0.087
  }
]
```

Additional information:

```
"Insert on request_to_print  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=422) (actual time=0.070..0.071 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=422) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.021 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.094 ms"
```

Comment: You'll have to catch a slow execution and provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for it. You can probably use auto_explain for that.

Comment: As in turn on slow execution / query logs?

Comment: As in read the documentation for auto_explain.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that is the uuid_generate_v4() field that is causing the issue. We have a column using that as the default, and now for some unknown reason it's slowed our inserts by a factor of 10. We used to get 25000 inserts a second, and now it's 2000. If I drop the column the speed returns, if I add it back it slows back down. Why the performance all of a sudden degraded is beyond me, but it might explain your sporadic performance.

Comment: Thanks so much for that tomh, I'll definitely take a look into it, but we're using uuid_generate_v4() on just about every table that requires a unique identifier, but this one insert is the only thing that's slow. Driving me nuts still! :)